# Keras ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_2: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to create a keras model that will be able to differentiate between 10 image classes. I'm creating 12 observation points for each object and then passing them to the model.

```
input_shape = (12, 1, 32, 32)
model = get_test_shared_model()
input = keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
views = SplitLayer(num_views)(input)  # list of keras-tensors
processed_views = []  # empty list
for view in views:
    x = model(view)
    processed_views.append(x)
```

At this stage I did the calculations on each observation point on its own and now I'm trying to merge them together using the Maximum layer.
The error occurs on the Conv2D line. 
Any thoughts on how to tackle this?

```
pooled_views = keras.layers.Maximum()(processed_views)
prediction = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(pooled_views)
```

The Split Layer source code is:

```
class SplitLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    """
    Layer expects a tensor (multi-dimensonal array) of shape (samples, views, 
    ...)
    and returns a list of #views elements, each of shape (samples, ...)
    """

    def __init__(self, num_splits, **kwargs):
        self.num_splits = num_splits
        super(SplitLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, x):
        a = [x[:, i] for i in range(self.num_splits)]
        return a

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return [(input_shape[0],) + input_shape[2:]]*self.num_splits


def get_test_shared_model():
    num_channels = 4  # for example
    cnn = keras.models.Sequential()
    cnn.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(num_channels, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                            activation='relu',
                            input_shape=(32, 32, 1)))
    cnn.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    cnn.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
    cnn.add(keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    return cnn
```

Comment: How your `pooled_views` look like? What is the dimension of the data. It's likely 2 and that's the problem.